# Need a gap at bottom of absolute div

Tags: html, css

I currently have an absolute div that I use for the main content of the page, I need to create a space at the bottom of the div, to allow the footer to show. The footer is fixed, so the absolute div is treated as the last element I guess, thus meaning that there's no space at the bottom, the idea is to create a sort of scrollin effect like so:

[First scroll in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY3j6.jpg)

This is on a larger screen, but the issue comes when it's rendered on a smaller screen, as there just seems to be no space at the bottom of the main content div.

Here's what I have currently:-

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="Navigation" class="transparent">
        <div id="nav" class="transparent">
            <div class="wrapper" class="transparent">
            <div class="navigation" class="transparent">
                <ul class="navigation-elements transparent" styles="cursor: pointer;margin-left: 10px;">
                    <li id="logo-li">
                        <a href="http://cms.manciniyoungphotography.com">
                            <img src="/img/logo.png" title="Mancini Young Photography" alt="Mancini Young Photography" id="icon"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li style='cursor: pointer;' id='navigation-link'  class='blog'  onClick="navClick(this); autoScroll('blog');">
                        <a href='#blog' onClick="return false; navClick(this); autoScroll('blog');">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style='cursor: pointer;' id='navigation-link'  class='contact'  onClick="navClick(this); autoScroll('contact');">
                        <a href='#contact' onClick="return false; navClick(this); autoScroll('contact');">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style='cursor: pointer;' id='navigation-link'  class='portfolio'  onClick="navClick(this); autoScroll('portfolio');">
                        <a href='#portfolio' onClick="return false; navClick(this); autoScroll('portfolio');">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style='cursor: pointer;' id='navigation-link'  class='about-us'  onClick="navClick(this); autoScroll('about-us');">
                        <a href='#about' onClick="return false; navClick(this); autoScroll('about-us');">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style='cursor: pointer;' id='navigation-link'  class='home selected'  onClick="navClick(this); autoScroll('home')">
                        <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="float: left;margin-left: 10%;"></span>-->
                        <a href='http://cms.manciniyoungphotography.com' onClick="return false; navClick(this);">Home</a>
                    </li>                               
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="main" style='background: #dadada url("/img/background_shapes.png") repeat-y scroll center top, url("/img/blue_bg.png") repeat-x scroll left top transparent;'>
    <div class="shapes">
        <div id="inner-main">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div id='firstBlockContainer'>
                    <div id='FBL'>
                        <div id="canvas-one" ></div>
                        <div id="canvas-two" ></div>
                        <div id="canvas-three" ></div>
                        <div id="home" class="parallax-cont"></div>
                        <div id="about-us" class="parallax-cont">
                            <div id="about-content" class="generic">
                                <div class="title">This is the title</div>
                                Hello, this is where the content for Mancini Young Photography's about us section will go.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="portfolio" class="parallax-cont"></div>
                        <div id="contact" class="parallax-cont">
                            <div id="contact-us-header">
                                <img src="/img/logo.png" />
                            </div>
                            <div id="contact-us-form">
                                <form name="contact-us" method="POST" action="">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="contact-form" />
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" class="contact-form" />
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Company Name" class="contact-form" />
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Website" class="contact-form" />
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Telephone No." class="contact-form" />
                                    <input class="form-control" type="textarea" placeholder="Message" class="contact-form" />
                                    <input type="submit" class="form-control" />
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="blog" class="parallax-cont">
                            <div class="previous-button"></div>
                            <div id="blog_container">
                                <div id="postContainer"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="next-button"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="main-content"></div>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/blog-post-loader.js"></script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" >
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="left leftFooter">
                <ul class='selected' style='color: #fafafa'>
                    <a href='http://cms.manciniyoungphotography.com' >Home</a>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <a href='#portfolio' style='color: #fafafa;'>Portfolio</a>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <a href='#blog' style='color: #fafafa;'>Blog</a>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <a href='#about' style='color: #fafafa;'>About Us</a>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <a href='#contact' style='color: #fafafa;'>Contact</a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="userFooterContents" ></div>
        </div>
        </br>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-content {
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #dadada;
    border-top: #0c0c0c;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 800px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-height: 10%;
    background: #26262B;
    box-shadow: -1px -2px 8px #0c0c0c;
    padding: 20px;
        width: 100%;
}
#copyright {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0;
    float: left;
    background: #0c0c0c;
    color: #A69F88;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

`#main-content` is the area where the main body of the content is, and the gap I need is to show #footer and #copyright

Here's the working example of the website:
http://cms.manciniyoungphotography.com/

Answer (score 0):

if i understand this right you probably make things a bit too complicated, but that's just me. :)

try these changes:

```
#main-content {
   top: 0;
   z-index: 0;
}
#footer {
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't want main content to be right at the top. As there is a header image as well and a navigation. I'll update the code to show the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand, you're going for full screen. There are many approaches, but try this:

```
#main-content {
z-index: 20;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
width: 100vw;
background: #dadada;
border-top: #0c0c0c;
height: 100%;
min-height: 800px;
vertical-align: top;
padding-bottom:10%;
z-index:-1;
}
#footer {
position: fixed;
z-index: 0;
bottom: 0;
min-height: 10%;
background: #26262B;
box-shadow: -1px -2px 8px #0c0c0c;
padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
z-index:2;
}
#copyright {
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
bottom: 0;
float: left;
background: #0c0c0c;
color: #A69F88;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: well, I tested your html + my code in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xofnokf0/ and it works fine for full screen. If you don't need full screen, see http://jsfiddle.net/sawzw7mt/ . For non full screen, set the main content to relative and that's it

Comment: Added a link to the website so you can get a better idea of what I'm talking about. I don't want the main content to be full screen, I want the main content to scroll over the footer to reveal the footer. The footer is fixed, but it is set as the lowest layer element, so it's hidden until you reach the gap at the bottom of the page where it is visible. Does that make sense?

Comment: got it. Then there are 2 scenarios. Are you having a more or less known height for the footer or will it be variable? Check http://jsfiddle.net/sawzw7mt/1/ And if known, replace `margin-bottom:20%;` for a known height, like 80px. However, if you want it to be it variable, you'll need to adjust that margin via media queries. What I don't understand is why you want this if the regular behavior of a site is to show the footer once you reach it, but there you go, hope that helps

Comment: See the thing is that I tried to add a margin-bottom of 20%, but it just does nothing. I don't know if you can inspect and try it yourself, but when I done it in the file, it did nothing